# How to cut a string after X apparition of a specific character in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string that looks lite that :
str = "aaaa-050-xxx-zzz"

I need to cut my string after the second '-'
So in this example, i want to get "aaaa-050"

The number of characters before and after each '-' isn't constant.

Then i need to remove the '-' in the new string to get "aaaa050"

What's the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several choices. Aside from just looping through the string looking for the second `-`, there are both regex and `String#split` solutions:

With a regular expression, you can find the first two segments without `-` in them separated by a `-` and then use them to form the replacement:

```js
var str = "aaaa-050-xxx-zzz";
str = str.replace(/^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-.*$/, '$1$2');
console.log(str);
```

Or there's a `split` solution where you split on `-` and then join the first and second segments:

```js
var str = "aaaa-050-xxx-zzz";
var parts = str.split("-");
str = parts[0] + parts[1];
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use the split method, it's easier to understand for me ! I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

If this structure is your pattern, you can split by `-` and join the parts:

```js
var str = "aaaa-050-xxx-zzz";
var splited = str.split("-");
var res = splited[0] + "-" + splited[1];
console.log(res);
```